# Aggregating Data in MongoDB based on properties values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB 3.4 and I need to create a query filter to fetch data from my mongo collection (`ProductionEventsCollection`). 
Some values are calculated "**on the fly**".

As these records are event based and future values depend on past values, if a value is changed in the past it affects the future sums.

I have a collection with the properties as written bellow:

```
[{
 _id: "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b64",
 piece_id: "12345",
 finish_date: "2018-11-26T17:15:09.795Z",
 total_produced: 500
},
{
 _id: "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b65",
 piece_id: "12345",
 finish_date: "2018-11-27T17:15:09.795Z",
 total_produced: 750
},
{
 _id: "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b66",
 piece_id: "12345",
 finish_date: "2018-11-28T17:15:09.795Z",
 total_produced: 250
}]
```

The idea is to get a collection like this:

```
[{
 _id: "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b64",
 piece_id: "12345",
 finish_date: "2018-11-26T17:15:09.795Z",
 previous_value: 0,
 total_produced: 500,
 new_value: 500
},
{
 _id: "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b65",
 piece_id: "12345",
 finish_date: "2018-11-27T17:15:09.795Z",
 previous_value: 500,
 total_produced: 750,
 new_value: 1250
},
{
 _id: "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b66",
 piece_id: "12345",
 finish_date: "2018-11-28T17:15:09.795Z",
 previous_value: 1250,
 total_produced: 250,
 new_value: 1500
}]
```

Based on the `finish_date` property, I should be able to calculate the `previous_value` sums until that date, and the `new_value` will be the previous calculated sum plus the `total_produced`.

**Previous value**

```
previous_value = SUM(past total_produced) until finish_date
```

**New Value**

```
new_value = previous_value + total_produced
```

Based on these collection values I need to return a json array, because I'll allow users to download a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation to get the result, the logic is to use `$reduce` to calculate the running total

aggregation pipeline

```
db.t32.aggregate([
    {$group : {_id : "$piece_id", data : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}}, 
    {$addFields : {data : 
        {$reduce : {
            input : "$data", 
            initialValue : [{previous_value :  0, total_produced : 0, new_value : 0}], 
            in : {$concatArrays : 
                [ "$$value",[{$mergeObjects : ["$$this", { previous_value : {$arrayElemAt : ["$$value.new_value", -1]} , total_produced : "$$this.total_produced", new_value : {$sum : ["$$this.total_produced",{$arrayElemAt : ["$$value.new_value", -1]}]}}]}]]
            }
        }}
    }},
    {$addFields : {data : {$slice : ["$data", 1, {$size : "$data"}]}}}
]).pretty()
```

sample collection

```
> db.t32.find()
{ "_id" : "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b64", "piece_id" : "12345", "finish_date" : "2018-11-26T17:15:09.795Z", "total_produced" : 500 }
{ "_id" : "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b65", "piece_id" : "12345", "finish_date" : "2018-11-27T17:15:09.795Z", "total_produced" : 750 }
{ "_id" : "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b66", "piece_id" : "12345", "finish_date" : "2018-11-28T17:15:09.795Z", "total_produced" : 250 }
```

aggregation result

```
> db.t32.aggregate([
... {$group : {_id : "$piece_id", data : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}},
... {$addFields : {data :
... {$reduce : {
... input : "$data",
... initialValue : [{previous_value :  0, total_produced : 0, new_value : 0}],
... in : {$concatArrays :
... [ "$$value",[{$mergeObjects : ["$$this", { previous_value : {$arrayElemAt : ["$$value.new_value", -1]} , total_produced : "$$this.total_produced", new_value : {$sum : ["$$this.total_produced",{$arrayElemAt : ["$$value.new_value", -1]}]}}]}]]
... }
... }}
... }},
... {$addFields : {data : {$slice : ["$data", 1,1000]}}}
... ]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "12345",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b64",
                        "piece_id" : "12345",
                        "finish_date" : "2018-11-26T17:15:09.795Z",
                        "total_produced" : 500,
                        "previous_value" : 0,
                        "new_value" : 500
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b65",
                        "piece_id" : "12345",
                        "finish_date" : "2018-11-27T17:15:09.795Z",
                        "total_produced" : 750,
                        "previous_value" : 500,
                        "new_value" : 1250
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "5bfc2a16b4f11f3760ed4b66",
                        "piece_id" : "12345",
                        "finish_date" : "2018-11-28T17:15:09.795Z",
                        "total_produced" : 250,
                        "previous_value" : 1250,
                        "new_value" : 1500
                }
        ]
}
>
```

Comment: Thank you, works great and as expected. I just needed to order it by `finish_date`, this can be achieved using  `{ $sort: { finish_date: 1 } }` this is needed for the sums.

Comment: `$mergeObjects` is from version 3.6 and above :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if such an aggregation is even possible in mongodb.
Sounds like a typical business logic for the sever side and therefore I would suggest fetching the relevant data to the server and perform all the computation there. That way things are much less complex and without any performance loss.